# ./myscript.sh not using current session locale

Tags: bash, docker

When executing a script (not sourcing) e.g. `./myscript.sh` it is not having the correct locale (it is set to `POSIX` instead of `UTF8` as my current session has).

If I source the file it does though. What do I need to do so that the when executing the file it will get the correct locale.

Current interactive session:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export TZ=UTC
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

`./myscript.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
locale
```

Outputs the following when running `./myscript.sh` in the current interactive session:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Afaiac it is running in a new shell (fine). What this new shell sources I don't know.

I have however NOT LOGGED OUT AND IN since setting the locale in my interactive session (this is set via a Dockerfile so not possible).

Comment: Does your script use a shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/sh` on the first line) ?

Comment: @Aaron It uses `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: What does `env | grep LANG` say in your interactive shell?

Comment: @melpomene Just updated the question with more info!

Comment: afaik the session isn't inherited when running scripts, as you expect, but it also won't load `.bashrc` first. The locale should be somewhere more system level

Comment: Can you reproduce this without Docker? If not it's a Docker question and you need to include Docker details